# How to read the Elm type signature with a lowercase type param?

Tags: elm

Here's the type signature for `Time.fps` from the [library documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Time):

```
fps : number -> Signal Time
```

Coming from Haskell, I'm wondering why the `number` type parameter is lower-cased and what that means in the Elm context. Is it a pseudo-typeclass? By contrast, I see other functions that use a proper concrete type for numeric parameters, e.g. from the `Basics` module:

```
toFloat : Int -> Float

round : Float -> Int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number` is a special type that can be either an `Int` or a `Float`. It is lowercased because it is not a specific type. You could think of it as a pseudo-typeclass, but unlike in Haskell you cannot add another type to `number`.

see http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#literals